# How to disable hooks when running shell scripts in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I would like to disable some hooks, e.g., sockets, when running shell scripts in Sails.js. One possibility is to put in .sailsrc:

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "sockets": false
  }
}
```

but that will also be applied when lifting a server.

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.js` you can prevent `sails` from loading the `.sailsrc` file when you **lift** the app.
In the last line of your `app.js` change this :

```
// Start server
sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

to this :

```
// Start server
sails.lift('sails');
```

**UPDATE**

You can leave your `.sailsrc` with the disabled hooks so you can run your shell scripts, and create another config file , name it whatever you want , I choose a random name here `randomName.json`, then start your app with this command **`node app.js --config randomName.json`** , you can put it in your package.json so you don't have to write it everytime, when running the command sails will lift **from** that `randomName.json`, so put there your desired configurations and leave `.sailsrc` for the shell scripts.

Comment: In our application, .sailsrc is usually used for lifting the app. Is there a way to have something like another .sailsrc for **sails run**?

Comment: What sails commands you run in your scripts that need the hooks to be disabled ?

Comment: This is a good solution. I want to disable hooks only for speed.